# Error: (root) Additional property service is not allowed - while using command docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose

I code on a Mac using VSCode. The folder, that includes all files is located on an external hard drive.

After writing my docker-compose.yml i use the command docker-compose up -d --build
and git the **error: (root) Additional property service is not allowed**

I then tried first to use docker build and it worked, but as soon as i use
docker-compose up, i get the same error message. What is an additional property service?
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

service:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 /eskills/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/eskill
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/postgres_data
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

[screenshot of docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uneee.png)

I tried to find all typos, checked my books, indentation, but i can not find, what i did wrong.
Here on stackoverflow i found similar errors and answers, but nothing about 'property service'.
Would you please see my code and let me know, what i have to change? Does it matter, that the whole folder /eskills is located on an external hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can't find anything about a "service" key is that it's actually called service**s**, not service, since you can define multiple.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#service-configuration-reference

Comment: Great. It was a typo. Thanks a lot. I had it also wrong in my notes i took, than.